# PrimeFaces wrong Date Format

Tags: date, primefaces, jsf-2

I tried to make PrimeFaces (6.1.7) calendar input with format of "M/d/yy" but it gives me only one digit for month and one digit for day (I can't write manually 12/12/17, when I'm writing "1" it jumps to the next digit without giving an option to write 12).

What can I do? Is there a known bug in PrimeFaces?

(I know I can write MM/DD/YY but I need this format because I'm taking it from java method)

The code used is as follows:

```
<p:calendar id="startDate" required="true" mask="true"
                pattern="M/d/yy"></p:calendar>
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: `because I'm taking it from java method` - what does this mean? You'd usually set a pattern according to the user locale.

Comment: The input mask behavior is enabled by the attribute `mask="true"` which you don't have set. Not sure how it could jump anywhere without a mask.

Comment: @VsevolodGolovanov Sorry, I forgot to add the "mask="true" here. anywhere - in my code it appeared already. And you're right, I usually set a pattern according to the user locale.

Comment: Why should it be a bug? You've set your pattern to M/d/yy, so there's only one char for the month and the day, so you already know what's your mistake. I don't really understand what's your problem with the java method. So give us more code (expecially the java method) to get more help.

Comment: It makes no sense to give one digit to the day. When I tried to use this pattern in Java - System.out.println("" + new SimpleDateFormat("M/d/yy").format(new Date()));  and it work as expected - not like PrimeFaces

Comment: @lastresort: You had the same line of thinking I did, so I also tested it and Dvir is right. The `M` means no 0 prefix is needed in input or output, but you should still be able to provide '10, 11 and 12'  as months.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spoke with PrimeFaces about it.

They said that it's a bug that will be fix in next elite release (6.1.8) and the 6.2 Community edition